# Self-hosted Git Server с поддержкой lfs locks

Tags: git, поиск-программ, git-lfs

Прошу подсказать ПО, которое может выполнять функции self-hosted Git Server с поддержкой [lfs locks API](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/File-Locking)

Основные требования к ПО:

- Запуск сервиса локально(на своем железе, "облачные" сервисы не подходят)
- Кроссплатформенность(как минимум Windows/Lnux)
- Наличие Web-интерфейса
- OpenSource(крайне желательно)
- FreeWare для небольшой команды(менее 20)
- Поддержка [git lfs lock API](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/File-Locking)

У нас много двоичных файлов, над которыми могут работать несколько человек.

Их мерж - боль.

Поэтому файлы нужно блокировать(лочить) на время работы одного из участников с этими файлами.

Сейчас используем [GOGS](https://gogs.io/).

Он подходит по всем требованиям, кроме последнего.

Comment: Тут [в доке](https://github.com/gogs/gogs/blob/main/docs/user/lfs.md) написано, что Gogs поддерживает LFS

Comment: @Vadik lfs да, lfs locks нет

Comment: ¿А будет ли толк от использования lfs lock? Как я понял, проверяется его наличие только непосредственно при пуше на сервер и ничто не мешает открыть и редактировать файл локально. В результате получается та же самая необходимость их мерджить

Comment: @user7860670 как я понимаю, там смысл в том, что локальные файлы по умолчанию readonly. чтобы их редактировать нужно залочить, обратившись с запросом к серверу. а по окончании работы - снять блокировку.